# C# how to use EmguCV to remove noise of a captcha?

Tags: c#, captcha, emgucv

I'm trying to learn how to remove noise of a captcha image. I started trying to find patterns in the images.

[image]

My algorithm

```
public void Decaptcha(string filePath)
{
    // load the file
    using (var src = new Mat(filePath))
    {
        using (var binaryMask = new Mat())
        {
            // lines color is different than text
            var linesColor = Scalar.FromRgb(0x70, 0x70, 0x70);

            // build a mask of lines
             Cv2.InRange(src, linesColor, linesColor, binaryMask);
             using (var masked = new Mat())
             {
                src.CopyTo(masked, binaryMask);
                int linesDilate = 3;
                using (var element = Cv2.GetStructuringElement(MorphShapes.Ellipse, new Size(linesDilate, linesDilate)))
                {
                    Cv2.Dilate(masked, masked, element);
                    pictureBox2.Image = OpenCvSharp.Extensions.BitmapConverter.ToBitmap(element);
                }

                // convert mask to grayscale
                Cv2.CvtColor(masked, masked, ColorConversionCodes.BGR2GRAY);
                using (var dst = src.EmptyClone())
                {
                    // repaint big lines
                    Cv2.Inpaint(src, masked, dst, 3, InpaintMethod.NS);

                    // destroy small lines
                    linesDilate = 2;
                    using (var element = Cv2.GetStructuringElement(MorphShapes.Ellipse, new Size(linesDilate, linesDilate)))
                    {
                        Cv2.Dilate(dst, dst, element);
                    }

                    Cv2.GaussianBlur(dst, dst, new Size(5, 5), 0);
                    using (var dst2 = dst.BilateralFilter(5, 75, 75))
                    {
                        // basically make it B&W
                        Cv2.CvtColor(dst2, dst2, ColorConversionCodes.BGR2GRAY);
                        Cv2.Threshold(dst2, dst2, 255, 255, ThresholdTypes.Otsu);

                        // save the file
                        dst2.SaveImage(Path.Combine(
                            Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath),
                            Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath) + "_dst" + Path.GetExtension(filePath)));
                        pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(fileName);
                        pictureBox3.Image = OpenCvSharp.Extensions.BitmapConverter.ToBitmap(dst);
                        pictureBox4.Image = OpenCvSharp.Extensions.BitmapConverter.ToBitmap(dst2);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But the result is not correct
Everyone can help me!!

[image]